# Modeling languages for Hardware platforms (embedded systems)

Tags: embedded, hardware, tools, modeling

I'm looking for some modeling languages in order to design hardware platforms in the context of embedded systems.

I already had a look at the following:

- [AUTOSAR](http://www.autosar.org/)
- [UMLMarte](http://www.omgmarte.org/)
- [SysML](http://www.sysml.org/)

I wonder if there are more modeling languages regarding this topic. So if someone knows one, please share it.

Answer (score 3):

SysML contains most of UML (or maybe even all of it, for all I know).  It looks like it should work well.  I'ts real flexible, and should handle electrical, mechanical, and any other system you can throw at it.  I've tried using it for embedded projects, but have had problems finding a version stable enough to play with that doesn't cost a bunch of money.